# Combine 2 strings to get an output in alternating sequence of each character from the two strings in objective c

Tags: objective-c

How do we combine characters from 2 strings and display the output? `string1` and `string2` combined to get `string3` with an output like below. I couldn't find any solutions and this code is working for me.

```
string1=@"ACEG";
string2=@"BDF";
Output:
ABCDEFG
// Anybody has an alternative solution to get this result.
{
    NSString *name1=@"ACEG";
    NSString *name2=@"BDF";
    NSString *name1Andname2=@"";
    NSInteger number;   
    NSMutableArray *charArray1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:name1.length];
    NSMutableArray *charArray2 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:name2.length];
    for (int i=0; i < name1.length;i++) {
        NSString *ichar1  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [name1 characterAtIndex:i]];
        [charArray1 addObject:ichar1];
    }
    for (int i=0; i < name2.length;i++) {
        NSString *ichar2  = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%c", [name2 characterAtIndex:i]];
        [charArray2 addObject:ichar2];  
    }
    if (name1.length>name2.length)
    {
        number=name1.length;
    }
    else
    {
        number=name2.length;
    }
    for (int i=0; i <= number;i++) {
        if(name1.length>i)
        {
            name1Andname2=[name1Andname2 stringByAppendingString:charArray1[i]];
        }
        if(name2.length>i)
        {
        name1Andname2=[name1Andname2 stringByAppendingString:charArray2[i]];
        }
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",name1Andname2);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want the result to be an alternation of each character of the two strings, your current approach is essentially the way to implement it. Though your code may not work with all possible Unicode characters since not all characters can be represented by strings of length 1. Below is a more robust solution that works with any characters.

```
NSString *name1=@"ACEG";
NSString *name2=@"BDF";

NSMutableArray *firstChars = [NSMutableArray array];

[name1 enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, name1.length) options: NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
    usingBlock: ^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [firstChars addObject: substring];
}];

NSMutableArray *secondChars = [NSMutableArray array];

[name2 enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, name2.length) options: NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
    usingBlock: ^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
    [secondChars addObject: substring];
}];

NSMutableString *result = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
NSInteger maxLen = MAX(firstChars.count, secondChars.count);
for (NSInteger i = 0; i < maxLen; i++) {
    if (i < firstChars.count) {
        [result appendString:firstChars[i]];
    }
    if (i < secondChars.count) {
        [result appendString:secondChars[i]];
    }
}

NSLog(@"Final string: %@", result);
```

Comment: This code is working with these 2 strings only. String1=@"ABCDEFG" String2=@"123456789" and the output should be "A1B2C3D4E5F6G789"

Comment: The code I posted will work with any two strings. Just change the value of `name1` and `name2`. If it is not working with other strings, please state what the two strings are and what output you expect from those two strings.

Comment: So it seems you want the result to be an alternating sequence of each character from the two strings. Your question makes it look like you want the result to be the combined characters in alphabetical order. You should update your question with a better sample.

Comment: See my updated answer. It now does what you want and it will work with strings containing any Unicode characters.